# Determinant and eigenvalues of a matrix when transposed with respect to the anti-diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, transpose

The determinant and the eigenvalues of a matrix doesn't change if the matrix is transposed: $\operatorname{det}\left(A^{T}\right)=\operatorname{det}(A)$ and $\det(A-\lambda I)=\det(A^T-\lambda I)$.

Does this two properties also hold true when the matrix is transposed with respect to the anti-diagonal? That is, $\operatorname{det}\left(A^{\tau}\right)=\operatorname{det}(A)$ and $\det(A-\lambda I)=\det(A^\tau-\lambda I)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Transposing with respect to the antidiagonal is equivalent to transposing in the normal way, then reversing the order of rows and reversing the order of columns.  Reversing the order of rows or columns either leaves the determinant the same or multiplies it by $-1$, depending on whether the number of rows/columns is even or odd.
Reversing both rows and columns thus leaves the determinant the same.